# Class variable not modified inside firebase closure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I have the class variable `universalGender` which I am retrieving from firebase using the `observeSingleEvent` code. I am setting this variable equal to a value that I am getting from firebase. A couple of weird things:  When I `print` the variable within the firebase closure, I am getting the expected output. As soon as I access this variable or print it outside of the closure, however, it is equal to an empty string, which is what I initialised this variable to be at the top of the class. Here's my code. Please help!!

```
var universalGender=String()

@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let databaseRef=Database.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let value=snapshot.value as! [String:String]
    let gender=value["Gender"] as!String
    self.universalGender=gender

}
```

Comment: if you want to access `universalGender` outside firebase closure then you need wait until API call completes. Because its coming from firebase server.

Comment: This [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/07/swift-closures-and-firebase-handling.html) I wrote may help. It shows some examples of Firebase closures in Swift.